# Can i use earlier version symfony plugin in symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony, gearman

I want to use http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGearmanPlugin in my project. This plugin has developed in symfony 1.4. I want to use in symfony2.How can i use that?

Answer (score 3):

Because symfony1.x and Symfony2 have completely different structures, it could be said that it is impossible use the plugin.

Instead you should find alternatives as a **bundle** for it. I think here it the one:
https://github.com/mmoreramerino/GearmanBundle

Comment: Or [this one](https://github.com/BeSimple/GearmanBundle), which seems to be inspired by the sf1.4 plugin

Comment: Ferhad Thank you for your advice. But i'm getting problem in last step.Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193103/requesting-client-jobs-in-gearman-bundle-in-symfony2